# Can jQuery add a plugin function to future members of a .class?

Tags: jquery-selectors

Here's something I don't know if it's possible, but here's my question:

My jQuery application has dynamically added entry fields. For example, a button "Add New Customer" adds a new entry form after the current one. So far, so good!

However, I find myself needing to add the mask functions I want to every newly created field, like this:

```
$("#customer_zipcode\\["+customerCount+"\\]).zipcodeMask(....);
```

`zipcodeMask(...)` is just an example function that checks to make sure the user's entered a correct zip code. Other similar masks for phone numbers, credit cards, etc. This part works great, but I have to set it for every newly created element I want to have a zip code mask.

I thought it would be awesome if there was something like `.live()` that could do the `.zipcodeMask()` call for every future instance of the zip code field.

I thought I'd make a class, such as `"UseZipCodeMask"`, and do something like `class="UseZipCodeMask"` in every input field that needs a zip code mask.

When I do this:

```
$(".UseZipCodeMask").zipcodeMask(....);
```

This works fine - for every existing element that has this class. If I create a new field with this class, it's doesn't have the `.zipcodeMask(...)` function working.

Is there a way to make my zip code fields get `.zipcodeMask(...)` automatically set for it? It would clean up the code a bit, there's a lot of code that adds `.zipcodeMask()` and other related functions every time some new input fields are created.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

What jquery version are you using?
You can use .delegate which means you would not have to "add the plugin" to newly created elements.